# First attempt of using plotly to display layers from a 3D array

Tags: r, plotly

This is my very first attempt using `plotly`in `R`… and I am struggling.

I would like to be able to use a cursor to navigate between successive layers of a 3D dataset of the form `(E, x, y)` by setting the cursor to certain values of `E`:

```
library(plotly)

# create fake data
# two vectors 
vec1 = c(2,13,22,98,4,8,8,1,10)
vec2 = c(2,4,6,7,1,55,32,12,1)

# 3D array
result = array(c(vec1,vec2),dim = c(3,3,2))

dimnames(result) <- c("E", "x", "y") # fails

fig <- result %>% # also fails not a data frame
  plot_ly(
    x = ~x,
    y = ~y,
    frame = ~E,
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'markers',
    showlegend = F
  )

fig
```

I encounter several issues. Could you please help me? Thank you!

Edits:

- The aim is to produce a 3D slicer, such as at 1:12 min in the [following video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZRYMItzwg8g), navigating between the virtual slices of a 3D volume.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by navigating between layers. Can you draw (hand-drawn is fine) something that exemplifies your idea? Or explain it in another way? You need data frames or vectors for Plotly, but I can get you there if I understand what it is you're trying to do. BTW, you used `dimnames` which is `list(row names, col names)`, since I assume you're only naming columns, `dimnames(result) <- list(NULL, c("E", "x", "y"))` Where `NULL` is used in place of row names. In Plotly `frame` is used for animation. I didn't think you were describing animation, though...

Comment: I have tried to add an explanation, editing my question.

Comment: Hi @kat, I am wondering if my edits answered your question. Would another package be more appropriate?

Comment: Check out what I added as an answer, it doesn't quite answer your question, but I definitely couldn't fit it in a comment! (I'll just edit my answer until I've answered your question.)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to use buttons, I think. However, you can definitely add mouse events, but that requires some Javascript.

See if this is sort of what you were looking for. In this version, you use the drop-down on the left (near the top) to choose which frame you want to view (instead of a mouse event).

In this version, I've changed your data to one data frame. You used 'E' to control the frame, but there are two '2'. If you wanted these grouped together then using E to set the frame is great. If you wanted these separated, then you need a distinct value to set the frames. (I added a column that equates to the row number, in lieu of using E.)

There is no animation here. Instead, I set each 'frame' to a separate trace (somewhat like a separate graph), then I set the visibility to all but one of them to false. When you use the dropdown, you're changing the visibility of the traces, so at any one point in time, you will only see one 'frame'.

If this is what you were looking for (short of the mouse events), and you're still interested in what we could do in the direction of a mouse event let me know. (I can just edit my answer.)

```
library(plotly)

# create fake data
# two vectors 
vec1 = c(2,13,22,98,4,8,8,1,10)
vec2 = c(2,4,6,7,1,55,32,12,1)

# 3D array
result = array(c(vec1,vec2),dim = c(3,3,2), 
               dimnames = list(NULL, c("E", "x", "y")))

# combine arrays, set as data frame
result <- rbind(result[, , 1], result[, , 2]) %>% as.data.frame() 

# add distinct value by row for frames
result$splt <- 1:nrow(result)  # because there are indistinct values in 'E'

result %>% 
  plot_ly(
    x = ~x, y = ~y,
    # frame = ~E,              this is commented out
    split = ~splt,             # <-- I added this (splits the graph by data row)
    type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', showlegend = F,
    visible = c(T, rep(F, nrow(result) - 1)) # I added this (visibility)
  ) %>% 
  layout(
    updatemenus = list(list(   # this creates the button on the graph
      buttons = lapply(1:nrow(result), function(k) { # loop through data
          vis = rep(F, nrow(result))     # all visibilities set to F
          vis[k] <- T                    # set current row to T
          list(method = "restyle",       # assign to button
               args = list("visible", vis),
               label = paste0("Frame ", result[k, ]$E))
        })
      )
    ))
```

[image]

Comment: I have been thinking further to this question. I am missing two things: (1) I would like to navigate between `(x,y)` images not scatter plots, (2) I would need to use javascript as you suggested to circulate between images to images in my large `(x,y,im)` datacube

Comment: This would mean that (i) the process checks what is the position of the mouse, (ii) when the mouse moves laterally, then the image is refreshed from the pile of images selecting the one that coincide with the lateral mouse position, the corresponding image number is displayed, (iii) I can escape this.